# WebSphere Liberty Profile: Context Root Not Found

Tags: websphere-liberty

I can't seem to get this working locally, even though the same WAR works on a remote server. When I go to visit my application locally, I get the "Context Root Not Found" error. The Liberty profile version is 8.5.5.5.

Here are the relevant files:

server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="tlc server">
  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>json-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>beanValidation-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>monitor-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>
  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" virtualHost="default_host" />
  <jdbcDriver id="DerbyJDBCDriver">
    <library name="DerbyLib">
      <fileset dir="C:\tools\servers\wlp\lib" includes="derbyclient-10.6.1.0.jar" />
    </library>
  </jdbcDriver>
  <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/TLCDataSource" id="derbyDataSource" jdbcDriverRef="DerbyJDBCDriver">
    <properties.derby.client databaseName="TLC" password="APP" user="APP" />
  </dataSource>
  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
  <application id="TLC_war" context-root="/TLC" location="C:\Users\nd26434\gitrepos\tlc\target\TLC-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" name="TLC_war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
      <privateLibrary>
        <fileset dir="C:\tools\servers\wlp\lib" includes="aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar" />
      </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
  </application>
</server>
```

message.log

```
[3/18/15 20:19:54:789 EDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0022W: Application TLC_war has not started in 30.018 seconds.
[3/18/15 20:20:03:174 EDT] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: TLC-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
[3/18/15 20:20:03:175 EDT] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module TLC-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT has been bound to tlc_host.
```

ibm-web-bnd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <virtual-host name="tlc_host"/>
    <resource-ref name="jdbc/TLCDataSource"
        binding-name="jdbc/TLCDataSource" />
</web-bnd>
```

ibm-web-ext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <reload-interval value="3"/>
    <context-root uri="TLC" />
    <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
    <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
    <enable-reloading value="true"/>
    <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="false" />
</web-ext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<virtual-host name="tlc_host"/>` from your `ibm-web-ext.xml` file. As you dont have `tlc_host`, but `default_host`.

Answer (score 0):

Context Root Not found is caused due to issue in one of the config files.
In my case, web.xml had an unclosed comment due to which the war was not built correctly.

This resulted in EAR file not updating.

**Solution:**

1. Compare you web.xml with previous versions to see what changed.
2. Add war to the server instead of the ear file to see the error. (If Running on Liberty Server)

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `podman` and Open Liberty, it was just very slow, with `top` in `podman machine ssh` showing 100% CPU use by `java`. Eventually the web interface went from "Connection refused" to "Context not found" to the Swagger UI.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, `Context Root Not Found` could be solved by reading log file `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\server_name\logs\console.log`, the error message help solve the problem.